# python - dataframe find duplicate with condition one row is different

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'd like to find the duplicate row with condition 1 column is different

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A', '1','Tom'], ['A','1','Tom'], ['A','1','Jerry'], ['A','1','Jerry'], ['A','2','Mary'],['B','1','Tony'],['B','1','Andy']], columns = ['company code','user id', 'user name'])
df[out]
             company code  user id    user name 
    0            A            1          Tom
    1            A            1          Tom
    2            A            1         Jerry
    3            A            1         Jerry
    4            A            2          Mary
    5            B            1          Tony
    6            B            1          Andy
```

The condition is 1 company can only have 1 user id with the same name.In this case the result would look like this because user ID is different name (Tom and Jerry) so it is a duplicated data.

```
             company code  user id    user name    Duplicate
    0            A            1          Tom          True
    1            A            1          Tom          True
    2            A            1         Jerry         True
    3            A            1         Jerry         True
    4            A            2          Mary         False
    5            B            1          Tony         True
    6            B            1          Andy         True
```

I've try to use duplicated() but the result is incorrect as below:

```
df['dup_id'] = df[['company code','user id']].duplicated(keep=False)
df['dup_name'] = df[['company code','user name']].duplicated(keep=False)
df['result dup'] = np.where((df['dup_id']==True & (df['dup_name']==False)),True,False)

      company code user id user name  dup_id  dup_name  result dup
0            A       1       Tom      True      True       False
1            A       1       Tom      True      True       False
2            A       1     Jerry      True      True       False
3            A       1     Jerry      True      True       False
4            A       2      Mary     False     False       False
5            B       1      Tony      True     False        True
6            B       1      Andy      True     False        True
```

Since there are duplicate name with Tom and Jerry so I've struggle for condition different name. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why `Tony` is not duplicated on lines 5 and 6?

Comment: This is just `df.duplicated(keep=False)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang You're right sorry for my mistake. I've edited my question. Thanks

Comment: @Erfan I try to use df.duplicated(keep=False) but since user id is a primary key so I want return True if name is different too.

Comment: You have that with `dup_id` then

Comment: @Erfan Actually if I have the same company / id and name, dup_id will return duplicated, I want to check with different name. Sorry my question is not clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last line by:

```
df['result_dup'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.dup_id or x.dup_name, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it:

```
df['Duplicate'] = df.duplicated(['company code', 'user id'], keep=False)
```

Output:

```
  company code user id user name  Duplicate
0            A       1       Tom       True
1            A       1       Tom       True
2            A       1     Jerry       True
3            A       1     Jerry       True
4            A       2      Mary      False
5            B       1      Tony       True
6            B       1      Andy       True
```